# How to get the total hr from start time to end time using 12 Hour Format in php

Tags: php, datetime, time

How can I get the total hour from two given time with "HH:mm:ss" format?

Here is my code:

```
   $start = 01:00:00 PM;
   $end = 02:00:00 PM;
```

Expected Output:

```
   $total = 1;
```

Comment: I would fix the errors which lie within your variables before continuing

Comment: You need to include a date if you want accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this:

```
$start = new DateTime('01:00:00 PM');
$end = new DateTime('02:00:00 PM');
$diff = $start->diff($end);
echo $diff->format('%H');
```

You can get more info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: what if i want the output will be at the same format in 12hourformat "HH:mm:ss"

Comment: This will fail in cases where, for example, `$start` is 11 PM and `$today` is 1 AM. Also in cases like the beginning and end of DST. You need dates to make it accurate.

Comment: does  DateTime::diff is accurate? i tried '09:00:00 PM' as my start and '02:00:00 PM'  on my endtime and it gives me 07:00:00 instead of 17:00:00

Comment: @ironcito how could it be? i have no idea to make it accurate

Comment: Both 7 and 17 could be true, depending on the date. PHP can't know if it's 9 PM today, tomorrow, yesterday...

Comment: @ironcito so how could we do some alternatives?

Comment: You need to be more specific. How to do that will depend on what information you have. If possible, stick to timestamps for keeping track of time, and only convert them to readable form for display.

Comment: do you really know how to do it? coz honestly i have no idea.

Comment: I don't know where you're getting the times and what you're using them for.

Comment: I'm working with reservation system. Where instructor of the university borrow materials from the committee.